# How to ask user input to draw number of shapes in python turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Write a program that uses turtle graphics to draw multiple equilateral triangles of increasing size, with a common starting point(vertex). The program asks the user for the initial side length, the increase between two consecutive triangles and the total number of triangles to draw. an example of the output when user enters side=50, increase=20 and number of triangles=5

```
import turtle
paper = turtle.Screen()
pen = turtle.Turtle()

for x in range(3):
    pen.forward(20)
    pen.left(120)


for x in range(3):
    pen.forward(40)
    pen.left(120)


for x in range(3):
    pen.forward(60)
    pen.left(120)

for x in range(3):
    pen.forward(80)
    pen.left(120)

for x in range(3):
    pen.forward(100)
    pen.left(120)
```

How to ask the user for input?

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Python 3, there's a new way to go about this.  The more recent turtle library adds the `numinput()` method:

```
numinput(title, prompt, default=None, minval=None, maxval=None)
```

So you can do your prompting using a GUI instead of the console.  (There's also a similar `textinput()` method.)  Here's how your code might look using this approach:

```
from turtle import Screen, Pen

paper = Screen()

length = paper.numinput("Triangles", "Enter initial side length:", default=40, minval=10, maxval=70)

increase = paper.numinput("Triangles", "Enter size increase:", default=30, minval=10, maxval=50)

# numinput() returns a float but we need an int for range()
triangles = int(paper.numinput("Triangles", "Enter the desired number of triangles", default=3, minval=1, maxval=5))

pen = Pen()

for triangle in range(triangles):
    for _ in range(3):
        pen.forward(length + triangle * increase)
        pen.left(120)

paper.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what you want:

```
import turtle

paper = turtle.Screen()
pen = turtle.Turtle()
person = input('Enter your initial side length: ')
triangle = input('Enter the desired amount of triangles: ')

for k in range(int(triangle)):
    for x in range(3):
        pen.forward((k+1)*float(person))
    pen.left(120)
```

Now a text in the Console should appear, asking for the side leght and by typing a Number, your triangles should appear.

Edit:
Forgot, that python beginns with k=0. Hence changed it to (k+1)*float(person). This should give you following image:
[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for answering the question. Is their a way for the user to input number of triangle to draw. In my code I made 5 triangle manually I want the user for input the number of triangle?

Comment: Did it. This should also needs an input for number of triangles. Would you click to accept my answer?

Comment: This code, as presented, doesn't draw triangles due to an indentation error.  Fixing that, it draws one less triangle than the user requests.